# why show this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()?

Tags: laravel

why show this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

(1/1) ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
$update = encomendas::
        join('encomendas_pagamentos', 'encomendas.id', '=', 'encomendas_pagamentos.id_encomenda')
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.entidade', $ENTIDADE)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.referencia', $REFERENCIA)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.valor', $VALOR)
        ->update(['encomendas.estado' => 2]);


   


    foreach ($update as $update) {

        Mail::send('emails.email-contacto', ['entidade' => $ENTIDADE,
        ], function ($messagem) use ($update) {

            $messagem->from('xxx@xxxxx.pt', 'xx');

            $messagem->to($update->email)->subject('xxxxx.pt notificação de pagamento');


        });
```

Comment: The update method will return the number of records that where updated. So $update will have no. of records updated and foreach requires collection of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

After update clone the data using get method in a variable. e.g.

```
$enc_updates = encomendas::join ...->get();
```

and in foreach use this `$enc_updates` to fetch the data

```
foreach ($enc_updates as $update) 
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Oh please don't go copy paste it, just create the query once and clone it to retrieve the data. A bit of text why this works would be great.

Comment: In the question, $update variable is used 3 times. For clarity I have written the entire code. Without copy paste, how could I tell him to replace the variables.

Comment: I mean copy/pasting the query as in `encomendas::join`. You can prepare this query, clone it, run update, clone it, use get.